# ng-controller with ng-include doesn't bind correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include, ng-controller

I have this A component, with `a.html` and `a.ts` files.

Inside `a.html`, the controller defined in `a.ts` (AController) is called `ar`.

Also, inside `a.html` call `b.html` with `ng-include`.

```
<div ng-include="'/public/templates/b.html'"
     ng-controller="AController as ctr"
     ng-if="someBoolean">
```

Inside `b.html`, there are a lot of divs concatenated, and they refer to the controller as `ctr`.

```
<div class="cardContent horizontalLayout" style="min-height:54px">
  <span>Last Name</span>
  <div class="flex"></div>
  <div class="horizontalLayout" ng-style="{'width': inputWidth}">
    <input  type="text" 
            class="materialInput flex smallPlaceholder" 
            ng-model="ctr.tempItem.lastName" 
            placeholder="Write here...">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cardContent horizontalLayout" style="min-height:54px">
  <span>First Name</span>
  <div class="flex"></div>
  <div class="horizontalLayout" ng-style="{'width': inputWidth}">
    <input  type="text" 
            class="materialInput flex smallPlaceholder" 
            ng-model="ctr.tempItem.firstName" 
            placeholder="Write here...">
  </div>
</div>
(...)
```

The problem: for some reason, the binding isn't working. `b.html` doesn't recognize `ctr` as AController, but `ng-include` works fine because the template is rendered.

Extra data: if I change the calling to `b.html` with the following, it works fine:

```
<div ng-include="'/public/templates/b.html'"
     ng-controller="AController as ar"
     ng-if="someBoolean">
```

So, it only works if I name the controller sarasa in b.html the same as in a.html. I don't want this, because b.html must be polimorfic to be reutilizable.

Why I'm not using a directive? For two reasons:

1. There is no logic here, it's only html.
2. I tried but I need replace property in true because the styles in a.html should apply in the divs too, and with replace in true I can't write more than one element because AngularJS doesn't like that. I'm exploring transclude option, but still is not a good idea using something so big to do this.

### Edit:

This is something similar to my controller:

```
namespace C {  

  class CController {
    
    public someProperty: string;

    constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {}  

    public someMethod(){}

  }
    
  App.controller('AController', ['$scope', CController]);
};
```

CController is the controller of `c.html`, which includes `a.html` with `ng-include`. So, CController is the controller of `a.html`, as it's written in the last line (App.controller(...))

Comment: Why not use a component? For more information see, [AngularJS Developer Guide - Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Comment: Seeing your controller code would help. It's possible you're not binding to `this` correctly

Comment: Does it work if you use ng-show="someBoolean" instead?

Comment: @georgeawg may I change the question? Why should I use a component instead of include a template? I really don't know about components and I really don't want to spend time researching if the ng-include alternative could work.

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias I could show you a reduce and modified version, because the code is from the company I work and it's very long.

Comment: @fwiw no, it doesn't.

Comment: @georgeawg SO doesn't let me to remove the format ot the first paragraph as you did. It says to me that some code isn't formatted.

Comment: Why are you injecting $scope into a class-based controller? If the controller is instantiated using "controller as" syntax, the controller should modify the `this` context, not $scope.

Comment: @georgeawg I really don't know. All the controllers in the app work like that. They inyect $scope, $rootScope and the services as I showed. I don't know AngularJS enough to understand the things it does internally.